# Firebase JS SDK OAuth2 request parameters: access_type: 'offline'

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication

I am building a serverless React PWA, where cloud functions manipulate API Resources (such as Classroom). And I am having a trouble gaining that offline authorized access. 
Seems that `firebase-web` method `signInWithPopup` that takes in Authentication Provider `GoogleAuthProvider()` does not support application of custom fields to the request such as `access_type`, `state`, `scope`.

```
this.auth.googleAuthProvider.setCustomParameters({
            access_type: "offline"
        }) //doesn't work
```

Is it possible to modify AuthProvider's request such that I receive my `refresh_token` back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there is no way currently. You can use [Google sign in JS sdk](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in) to sign with Google. This would provide you with the Google ID token, access token and refresh token.

You can then [sign in with Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin#expandable-2-label):

```
 var credential = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
      googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token);
  // Sign in with credential from the Google user.
  firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential).catch(function(error) {
    // Handle Errors here.
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
    // The email of the user's account used.
    var email = error.email;
    // The firebase.auth.AuthCredential type that was used.
    var credential = error.credential;
    // ...
  });
```